# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am developing an android application including native code

First I compile a prebuilt library. The Android.mk file is *project_path/jni/qt-library/Android.mk* :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := qt5Core-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libQt5Core.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += qtbase/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then I compile my library whose the Android.mk file is *project_path/jni/my-library/Android.mk* :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := myLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_qtsignaux_Library.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += Receiver.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += Emitter.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += moc_Receiver.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += moc_Emitter.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := qt5Core-prebuilt

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../qt-library/qtbase/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I compile the jni folder using the ndk-build script, everything works well but get the following error when calling :

```
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("myLibrary");
  }

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.example.qtsignaux-1/lib/arm/libmyLibrary.so"
```

Notice I unziped the apk folder and every libaries : *libQt5Core.so, libmyLibrary.so and libgnustl_shared.so* are in the lib/armeabi/ and lib/armeabi-v7a/ folders

My Application.mk file looks like :

```
APP_ABI += armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
```

I don't really understand what the error means and why the system try to load a library in the *application_package_name/lib/**arm*** folder. Does this folder really exist or this is just armeabi and  armeabi-v7a in my situation?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The error means that your library defined a `JNI_OnLoad` function, and returned `JNI_ERR` from it. If you didn't define a `JNI_OnLoad` function then you need to figure out where it's being pulled in from, and why it might be failing.

Comment: Hi fadden thank for answering. I still do not understant because I have only one function in my libray named startTest()

Answer (score 3):

I finally fixed my problem. This was because of libQt5Core.so file

Indeed this library implements the JNI_OnLoad() function  in which it tries to load some java classes contained in an external jar file.

To solve my problem I included the right jar file in the /libs

Comment: Which jar is that?

Comment: Hi Matferib, this was one of these libraries :
QtAndroid-bundled.jar
cessibility-bundled.jar
QtAndroidBearer-bundled.jar
QtAndroidBluetooth-bundled.jar
QtAndroidWebView-bundled.jar
QtMultimedia-bundled.jar
QtPositioning-bundled.jar
QtSensors-bundled.jar
I got them from the Qt sources

Comment: Cool, my app is still crashing after I call QApplication. Do you use android_ndk_glue (like pure C++ code) or are you creating the activity in java?

Comment: I create the activity in java and initialize the c++ part loading the .so files